# MySQL, Best character set for my scenario?

Tags: mysql

In the process of designing a database, I have the following columns and I am not sure which character set to use:

**id**: 20 ascii characters BUT **all letters are small**. Can I save space by taking advantage of that fact? I will search based on this, as its a primary key.

**about**: should support utf8, 256 characters max. I will never sort based on this, nor will I search based on this. Should I used utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci?

Comment: even if you have your id at 256 it would not be a problem. make it unsigned though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use an `INT` column as your `PRIMARY KEY`. MySQL uses this in all derived indexes, so if you choose a non-`INT` key you'll have enormous overhead to deal with.

If you need a secondary "identifier" column that's different, like 20 characters, define that column as `VARCHAR` and give it a `UNIQUE` index constraint.

There's nothing in your description that goes against the sane default of using UTF-8 as your encoding. The two options you're talking about are *collation*, which specifically refers to things like sort order, character equivalence, and upper/lower case mapping. Those are more subjective.

How many records are you anticipating you'll need to store? It's not even worth fussing over bytes unless you're dealing with hundreds of millions of these things.

Comment: I am looking for a 500m row database. Regarding the primary key, I have no option. It HAS to be that 20 character id. Is it a good idea to convert this 20 character id to a 40 character number and use this a a primary key?

Comment: Regarding te character set, which is faster: latin1 or ascii?

Comment: There's no faster between those two, they're both single-byte character sets. In fact, I doubt you can find a measurable difference between those and UTF-8. The only way to know for sure is to benchmark, of course. Also there's no native storage for 40 character numbers. `BIGINT` is a 64-bit native type, but that's not enough digits for what you want. If you're planning on 500M rows, I'd use that as your primary ID, and have a secondary `UNIQUE` index on your identifier column.

Comment: With that many rows, you probably want to plan for either table partitioning or sharding at the outset. It's usually better to have a large number of smaller tables than one gigantic one if you can structure your data that way.

Comment: Will I really see difference between an int and a char primary key? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: MySQL's indexing engine uses the primary key as a row identifier in all indexes, so using a character primary key can enormously bloat your index, especially if they're 40 characters or more vs. the 4 or 8 using `INT` or `BIGINT`. Other databases like Postgres have their own internal row identifier to avoid this.

Comment: If the length is the same, does char vs int make any difference?

Comment: The length won't be the same. `CHAR` has a *minimum* of one byte of overhead, so a three character string is equivalent to an `INT`. Use `INT` or `BIGINT` for best performance.